# Referencing a project in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I am a bit new to using `Eclipse` and I was hoping someone could explain to me how to `reference` a project in `Eclipse`.

In my project I currently want to reference [JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) into my project. I was taking a look at [ReferencingLibraryProject](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) but this wasn't very helpful. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the these steps,

- Go to File Menu and Select "Import" option
- In the Import Dialog, select last option "Other" and select "Checkout Projects from SVN", Click on Next Button

> [image]

- Select First option "Create New Repository Location"; Click on Next Button

  > [image]
- In the Url text box, enter location https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator ; click on Next Button

> [image]

- Click on Finish

Now you can see the project in your eclipse's project explorer and your current Workspace.

Comment: But there is no option like Other then...?

Comment: ok, then means [**SVN** plugins](http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/) are missing in your eclipse, you need to first install those plugins.

Comment: Please inform me how can I install?

Comment: @RahulPatel, i updated my comment with the plugin link, visit it and install it :)